# Was it ever correct to wire a NEMA 10-30 dryer outlet with a ground instead of neutral?

Tags: wiring, code-compliance

So I believe this could be more of a semantic argument than anything, but someone is telling me that old dryer outlets are wired with a ground and no neutral, but its my understanding that a 10-30 has only a neutral that doubles as a ground, and there is no independent ground.  That's the purpose of the newer 14-30 - adding a ground to the 10-30 that didn't have one.

[image: NEMA 10-30]

So, in practice were these wired with an insulated white wire (neutral), or were they wired with a green or bare ground?  My assumption is that a "ground" wasn't used because the neutral must carry voltage for the motor and electronics that operate at 120v.  To be clear, I fully understand the electrical theory, I'm just not sure if historically a ground-type-wire was used on these receptacles.

Comment: Would it not depend if it was wired with 10/2 or 10/3 cable?  /2 would only have ground for neutral use, since white(neutral) would be needed to be second hot.

Comment: That's the question - I'm not sure if something like a 10/2 with a bare ground was ever allowed on these since they supply 240/120v.  Also I believe that cables used to be sold without a ground for this purpose.

Comment: I believe everything in old dryers operated at 240, so they didn't need a neutral.   And bear in mind that most electronics operate at low voltage (6-24v), so even at 120v they'd have to have a transformer to provide low voltage. Spec'd properly a transformer with a primary winding for 240 could also provide low voltage.   Also, motors can easily be designed for true 240 w/o needing a neutral ...they are very common. I'll admit, I DK what the neutral is used for in modern dryers.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson, well if you look at the NEMA classification the 10 series (like 10-30) is listed as a 240/120v outlet.  Regardless of dryer design, the outlet provides both voltages.  Also, basic dryers didn't have "electronics", just a heating element, drum motor, and a timer motor that controlled a series of relays.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yep, old dryers were dead simple.   I have no issue with the 4 wire dryer outlet requirement....I just DK what the 120v is used for and why it's needed. IE: In Europe everything is 230-240 and they have dryers! LOL

Answer (score 6):

Neutral and ground are totally separate systems that don't connect anywhere, except for a deliberate equipotential bond in the main panel.  However, the way this bond is implemented confuses the hell out of people.  (rather than the formality of totally separate bars with a connecting bond wire, builders are allowed to toss circuit grounds on the neutral bar.  It's a sad practice because it makes it impossible to clamp an ammeter around the equipotential bond wire to detect current moving on it.)

Fortunately, NEC 2020 calls for a main breaker at the meter, which has the side effect of moving the N-G equipotential bond to the meter-main. And the "master panel" where all the breakers are, will show separate N and G. Yay!

> someone is telling me that old dryer outlets are wired with a ground and no neutral

Someone is wrong, and probably violated Code when they did their installations, and are engaged in vanity defense.  NEMA 10 is clearly defined.

[image]

> but its my understanding that a 10-30 has only a neutral that doubles as a ground, and there is no independent ground. That's the purpose of the newer 14-30 - adding a ground to the 10-30 that didn't have one.

That is exactly right.  If one wanted a socket with no neutral, for a compressor, welder, EV charger and the like, the NEMA 6-30 is the socket for that.

However, 10-30's neutral doesn't double as a ground at all.  What is happening is that NEC allowed (from 1966 to 1995) attaching the dryer's chassis *to neutral* on the logic that neutral rarely fails because those sockets are rarely disturbed. Slowly, data rolled in showing that assumption was developing a body count.  Usually reported as *mis-wired* outlets, because the news cribs off court dockets, and that's what plaintiffs allege. Actually they were correctly wired (per pre-1996 Code) and the neutral wire simply got loose, energizing the chassis.

In fact, it has always been illegal to use /2+ground cable to wire a dryer.  In 1966 when the exception was made for dryers and ranges, the idea was to let suppliers "use up" their remaining stocks of 30-50A "/3 no-ground" and SE cable, since these were functionally obsolete the moment NEC 1966 dropped.  SE cable has a bare neutral, but its insulation is rated for that.  NM cable's isn't.  **Once those stocks of obsolete wire were gone, the only legal choice would be /3 w/ground cable**.  However, there were enough nitwits (including nitwit inspectors) who misinterpreted this rule, doing "/2 w/ground" and abusing NM ground as neutral, which it isn't rated for.  This confusion is why it was explicitly outlawed in 1996.

> So, in practice were these wired with an insulated white wire (neutral), or were they wired with a green or bare ground?

**Insulated** white wire -- except for the odd case of SE cable, which has a bare mesh neutral and outer sheath rated to insulate that, so a "naked" white wire if you will.  (SE cable is nominally for Service Entrances hence SE; which is on the utility side of the main disconnect, so ground doesn't exist yet. 30-50A SE cable went obsolete because power companies no longer offered service that small).  No other cable type is allowed a bare *neutral*.

There was absolutely no valid case for attaching a green wire to a NEMA 10 socket (unless the wire was #4 or larger in which case the insulation color can be overridden by phase tape).

But then, there is no valid case for using a NEMA 10 socket period, post-1996.  If you're wondering why they're in stores, it's for replacement of a broken NEMA 10 that was legal when installed. Obviously, over 99% of purchases are put to an illegal use, but freedom isn't free.

Comment: What is the meaning or system or significance in the number before the hyphen in these NEMA __-30 receptacles?

Comment: @Jim Series.  1 = 120V no ground 5 = 120V w/ground 2 = 240V no ground 6 = 240V w/ground 14 = 240V w/neutral+gnd

Comment: Is it just an arbitrary assisgnment of numbers to these types or is there some code or system?